# How to render streamlines in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to render streamlines in Unity. Streamlines are a lot of spacial curves and each vertex has its own color. Like the following image:

[image]

Unity's LineRenderer seems not able to assign colors to individual nodes. So what should I do?

Comment: *`Unity's LineRenderer seems not able to assign colors to individual nodes.`* That's when I'd start using multiple line renderers (use a list for each true-line?) or write my own extension (or reimplementation) of LineRenderer. I haven't tried to do the latter, so I don't even know if it'll work (in theory you can extend Unity classes, in practice you run into some WEIRD errors).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Mesh with [MeshTopology.Lines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshTopology.html) or [MeshTopology.LineStrip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MeshTopology.html)

Straight from the doc:

> ...in some cases you might want to render complex things that are made up from lines or points. Creating a Mesh with that topology and using it to render is usually the most efficient way.

Below is a script that creates a line strip mesh. Just place it on an empty GameObject.

The mesh looks like this: 
[image]

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class LineStrip : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {       
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));

        int n = 512;    
        Vector3[] verts = new Vector3[n];
        Color[] colors  = new Color[n];
        int[] indices = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // Indices in the verts array. First two indices form a line, 
            // and then each new index connects a new vertex to the existing line strip
            indices[i] = i;
            // Vertex colors
            colors [i] = Color.HSVToRGB( (float)i/n, 1, 1 );
            // Vertex positions
            verts[i] = new Vector3( i / 64f, Mathf.Sin( i/32f ), 0);
        }

        Mesh m = new Mesh
        {
            vertices = verts,
            colors = colors
        };

        m.SetIndices(indices, MeshTopology.LineStrip, 0, true);

        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = m;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know that `MeshTopology.Lines` existed